ValueError: too many values to unpack (hide_text_in_image(image_path, text)
I can't figure out how to fix this error.
Exception has occurred: ValueError
too many values to unpack (expected 3)
File , line 25, in hide_text_in_image
r, g, b = pixel
^^^^^^^
File  line 46, in 
hide_text_in_image(image_path, text)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
The whole code
from PIL import Image
def text_to_bits(text):
bits = ''.join(format(ord(char), '08b') for char in text)
return bits
def hide_text_in_image(image_path, text):
img = Image.open(image_path)
bits = text_to_bits(text)
pixels = list(img.getdata())

encoded_pixels = []
bit_index = 0

for pixel in pixels:
    if bit_index < len(bits):
        r, g, b = pixel
        r = (r & 0xFE) | int(bits[bit_index])
        g = (g & 0xFE) | int(bits[bit_index+1])
        b = (b & 0xFE) | int(bits[bit_index+2])
        encoded_pixels.append((r, g, b))
        bit_index += 3
    else:
        encoded_pixels.append(pixel)

encoded_image = Image.new(img.mode, img.size)
encoded_image.putdata(encoded_pixels)

encoded_image.save("encoded_image.png")

text = "Hello, this is a hidden message!"
image_path = "pngwing.com.png"
hide_text_in_image(image_path, text)
I tried to find the answer on the Internet, but I didn't understand anything.

If you do r, g, b = pixel, you expect that pixel is an iterable, like a list or tuple. In your case, pixel has too many values for the number of variables to want to assign values to. As an example:
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> y, z = x
ValueError: too many values to unpack

>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> y, z, a = x
>>> x
1
>>> z
2
>>> a
3

You could build in a check to assert that the number of values and variables are matched:
for pixel in pixels:
    if bit_index < len(bits):
        if len(pixel) == 3:
            r, g, b = pixel
        else:
            print("Pixel doesn't contain three values, assignment to r, g and b is ambigious")

